# Power on by keyboard/mouse doesn't work on my Gigabyte motherboard

Tags: keyboard, motherboard, bios, mouse, power

My Gigabyte z170x Gaming 3 motherboard comes with a feature that allows the PC to be turned on by keyboard or mouse. Can even set a password for keyboard boot so if you type the password while the computer is off, the PC would power on.

Unfortunately, none of these features seem to work for me. Both my keyboard and mouse are USB and this is a modern motherboard, so I doubt it's a PS/2 only thing.

I checked in BIOS and the ERP option is disabled, that means the keyboard and mouse should both be getting power, although curiously, none of them seem to show their respective LED lights when the PC is powered off. I also disabled Windows 10 fast startup so that the PC can fully shut down.

What could be causing this? Could it be that these features are there for legacy reasons and are non-functional on modern builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z170x-gaming3_e.pdf).

*1. Power On By Keyboard*

**Allows the system to be turned on by a PS/2 keyboard wake-up event.**

**Note: To use this function, you need an ATX power supply providing at least 1A on the +5VSB lead.**

- Disabled Disables this function. (Default)
- Any Key Press any key to turn on the system.
- Keyboard 98 Press POWER button on the Windows 98 keyboard to turn
  on the system.
- Password Set a password with 1~5 characters to turn on the system.

*2. Power On Password*

Set the password when Power On By Keyboard is set to Password.

Press  on this item and set a password with up to 5 characters and then press  to accept.
To turn on the system, enter the password and press .
Note: To cancel the password, press  on this item. When prompted for the password, press  again without entering the password to clear the password settings.

*3. Power On By Mouse*

**Allows the system to be turned on by a PS/2 mouse wake-up event.**

**Note: To use this function, you need an ATX power supply providing at least 1A on the +5VSB lead.**

- Disabled Disables this function. (Default)
- Move Move the mouse to turn on the system.
- Double Click Double click on left button on the mouse to turn on the
  system

**Looks like you were wrong. It does need to be done by a PS/2 device.**

Comment: How disappointing... Thank you.